# Adding code for client side validation into a .jss file

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

so i am trying to add client side validation into a javascript file... i have copied my code below... the code i am focusing on is the very last line. **i want to make it so the client side will ONLY accept space characters or lower and uppercase letters!**

on down the page there is also some 'truefeedback' and 'falsefeedback' variables for the 'notes' field' aswell as a 'formcheck.' and a 'validationtype.'

thanks

```
//set up the objects that contain the validation data for regex. These values must use the same name as the id of the form input.

var myreg = new Object();// set up the object containing the regex expressions to be used.

myreg.telephone = /^\(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?\(?(?:0\)?[\s-]?\(?)?|0)(?:\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}|\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4}|\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3})|\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5}|8(?:00[\s-]?11[\s-]?11|45[\s-]?46[\s-]?4\d))(?:(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?\s?|\#)\d+)?)$/g;

myreg.telmobile = /^\(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?\(?(?:0\)?[\s-]?\(?)?|0)(?:\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}|\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4}|\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3})|\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5}|8(?:00[\s-]?11[\s-]?11|45[\s-]?46[\s-]?4\d))(?:(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?\s?|\#)\d+)?)$/g;

myreg.postcode = /^(GIR ?0AA|[A-PR-UWYZ]([0-9]{1,2}|([A-HK-Y][0-9]([0-9ABEHMNPRV-Y])?)|[0-9][A-HJKPS-UW]) ?[0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})$/g;

myreg.email = /^.+?\@.*?$/;

**myreg.notes = /[A-Za-z]+/;**
```

I want my webpage to give me a message that only space characters and lower/upper case letters can be accepted in the 'notes' field.

Comment: So what you need is a regex that only accepts space characters or lower and uppercase letters? What is lower than an uppercase character.

Comment: yes thats it sorry !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will accept only text that contains letters or spaces:

```
/^[A-Za-z\s]*$/
```

**A-Z** is uppercase character. **a-z** is lowercase characters and **\s** are spaces.
Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks very much friend ! wish i could upvote you but i dont have enough reputation!

Comment: Glad I could help !